# Magento2 problem in Authorize.net

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, authorize

All admin Configuration perfect set.

But in front side after place order Continue Loader but not redirect thank you page. Order add in Admin side and Amount Not cut in customer account.

I use magento version 2.0.10 with VES pencil theme

Please help if you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting infinite loading animation, usually it means that you have some critical issue on the backend side. First of all, you need to check the error details. For this purpose, check your log files:

- var/log/exception.log
- webserver error.log

Or you can enable developer mode for Magento 2 in your shell:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

After this you should have a detailed error trace right in the response body of your order place request. Just check the response body of the place order request in your browser right after clicking the "Place Order" button (in Chrome you can track all requests in the Network tab of the developer tools pane).